# PuTTY psftp command line with proxy authentication

Tags: putty, psftp

Any idea how to connect below PuTTY `psftp` command with proxy authentication (SOCKS5)?

```
psftp username@host -P portnumber -pw password
```

Answer (score 4):

PuTTY and its tools have no command-line arguments to setup a proxy.

You have to pre-configure a stored session with the proxy.

Or of course, you can create an ad-hoc stored site automatically.

```
set REG_ADD=reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\AdHoc /f

%REG_ADD% /v HostName /t REG_SZ /d host
%REG_ADD% /v UserName /t REG_SZ /d username
%REG_ADD% /v Protocol /t REG_SZ /d ssh
%REG_ADD% /v PortNumber /t REG_DWORD /d 22
%REG_ADD% /v ProxyMethod /t REG_DWORD /d 2
%REG_ADD% /v ProxyHost /t REG_SZ /d proxy

psftp -load AdHoc -pw password
```

Comment: Very helpful answer Martin! I'd like to add that we can specify the proxy port by `%REG_ADD% /v ProxyPort /t REG_DWORD /d 1080`

Comment: The stored session info is only stored for the Current User. This has created some challenges in our case, where the psftp.exe script was executed by a user, which was meant to be non-interactive.